# Word for when two people type the same thing at the same time in chat

Tags: expressions

I have the distinct feeling there's a word often used when two people type the same thing at the same time in Internet chat contexts. Not necessarily *exactly* the same words, but closely related.

Maybe I've even come across it myself but forgotten it. All I can think of now is *"Snap!"*, but that sounds a bit lame in this day and age (who plays cards nowadays, with all these video games?).

Comment: This is called "Jinx! You owe me a Coke" in regular conversations.

Comment: I'm familiar with some common responses to that, like “great minds think alike (GMTA)” and “jinx,” but I'm not aware of any terms used to describe the phenomenon.

Comment: @Oldcat Damn.  I forgot to read the comments before posting!  But, as I've fleshed out a diatribe on the rules of the Jinx game, I will let it stand.  Especially, because, I was the one typing simultaneously to Fumble in the first place!

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. I was talking to my track coach today's and I needed to use this word but my mind was blank! I think I could be "simultaneously" but I'm not sure! It's driving me crazy!

Comment: related: [How do you properly say “missing each other” (that's SO the wrong word!)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116690/how-do-you-properly-say-missing-each-other-thats-so-the-wrong-word)

Comment: @Oldcat, the full saying is: "Jinx. 1, 2, 3, ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.  You owe me a coke. Stop."  The jinxer who gets to the end first wins.

Answer (score 9):

If it were spoken word, one would yell "Jinx!"  (Alternately, "Jinx, buy me a coke!")

And, according to the rules of the game when I grew up, be unable to speak until they purchased a Coke for the yeller.  If they spoke prior to paying the fine, they were subjected to a hard punch in the upper arm.

As to its use in chat . . . Well, I think it could be applicable.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the "you owe me a coke" construction from @Oldcat than "buy me . .  .". In chat -- JYOMAC, perhaps?

Comment: @joseph_morris JYOMAC.  Yeah, I like it.  It types well, too.  Fairly easy to find on the keyboard.  It is *rather* hard to punch people over the internet, though.

Comment: Yes, it was actually used to keep the younger ones quiet, if I'm remembering the way my kids did it. :)

Comment: @fumblefingers Stupid autocorrect!  It loves to insert that apostrophe. Thanks for catching my error and editing so I didn't appear to be a ninny!

Comment: I did wonder. I'm pretty sure I did another **it's** on one of your posts before. In the context of your writing in general, but I didn't think it was likely you wouldn't have *known* which version takes the apostrophe. But every now and then I've caught myself writing things like *there* for *their* - which looks absolutely *awful* if I notice it afterwards (and I don't even have the luxury of blaming "autocorrect", since I don't use anything like that! :)

Comment: Our version of Jinx was "pistache" (Dutch for pistachio). Also, it wasn't about buying the other a soda. When "pistached", you were not allowed to speak unless your first name was spoken. It didn't have to refer to you, the name just had to be mentioned. Nicknames don't count, which was a big problem in our friend group as practically everyone had a nickname.

Comment: @Flater Our version in Scotland was 'jinx' bur the rules for being allowed to speak again was your name being spoken, as in your version.

Comment: @Spagirl - We did this too with “Jinx” and names being spoken.  (US:NY)

Answer (score 1):

In radio comms this is 'crosstalk' and could apply to text as well. Crosstalk can mean several related things, but generally means interference between channels or between halves of a half-duplex channel.

The [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20talk) definition isn't as specific as its use in radio jargon.

Comment: In my experience with comms, crosstalk refers to when two or more people try to transmit a message at the same time, although does not mean they are trying to say the same thing, which I think is what the original post is asking for. Good to see some comms lingo given some air-time though!

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't read the OP closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

it is called synchronicity. when two people come up with something at the exact same time.

Comment: Reference.. ...?

Answer (score 0):

The word I think you're looking for is **simpatico** (sometimes spelled sympatico). My friend and I experience this a lot when we are texting.  As I am texting her a message and hitting the send button, I receive a nearly identical message from her. It's an uncanny experience at times.

Comment: Reference....  ?