# Isn't a comma necessary?

Tags: grammar

> I was jumping about up to my thighs in the waters.

Is a comma necessary after "about", or in another place in the sentence?

Answer (score 8):

Both are possible, and have slightly different meanings.

With a comma, you are saying that you were "jumping about":

> I was jumping about, up to my thighs in the waters.

The second way to parse it, you were just "jumping" and the waters were "about up to your thighs":

> I was jumping about up to my thighs in the waters.

In which case you could also place a comma after jumping:

> I was jumping, about up to my thighs in the waters.

Comment: I was jumping about, about up to my thighs in the waters.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was about to have a bout of about 20 minutes of jumping about, about up to my thighs in the waters about.

Comment: @Digital Chris: I was about to say that! (Is this a context where I could reasonably say ["Jinx!"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152947/) instead? If so, can I have a glass of wine? I don't drink Coke! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need commas after about and thighs. Up to my thighs is a parenthetical phrase and needs to be offset. (I'm no grammarian, so feel free to behead me for being wrong on that.)

Comment: That would be one comma too many, even for prescriptivists, I think. Up to my thighs in water, I jumped about.

Comment: @Susan I would read it as:  I was jumping about in water. (The water was up to my thighs).  Not sure if that is making my point clearer.

Comment: Yes, I did understand your point, but I don't think you need to close off everything that can sometimes be taken as a  parenthetical. This reads badly: *I jumped about, up to my thighs, in water. It's a mediocre sentence turned ogre.

Comment: @Susan LMAO!  I like that!  Turned ogre!