# What is the equivalent of sub-/supersonic for the speed of light?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

We have subsonic and supersonic for speeds below or above the speed of sound. What is the equivalent for the speed of light?

Comment: _Superluminal_ or _FTL_ for the positive, but nothing special for ordinary velocities, even relativistic ones. _Sublight_ or _sub-lightspeed_ are some of the terms that appear in science fiction stories, but they're guessing at future usages rather than reporting them. Since nothing moves faster than light that we know of, there's little non-SF usage.

Comment: Sci-fi writers sometimes use [FTL](http://www.internetslang.com/FTL-meaning-definition.asp) for "Faster Than Light", but obviously so far as the boffins are concerned no such thing is possible anyway. And we don't really need ["sub-light speed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sub-light+speed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) since that's basically everything except light. But there are several thousand written usages to show that people *do* use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was just typing the same about the lack of necessity for sub-lightspeed.

Comment: @David: [Oh, my sainted aunt!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154284/how-can-i-express-strong-emotions-without-using-biblical-or-profane-language#comment320265_154284) Who would have to buy the Cokes in a three-way [Jinx](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152947/)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You are ruining the word three-way.

Comment: @David: Not at all - they're ***jinks***, as in [*Philip Roth has a scene in Portnoy's Complaint wherein Alexander Portnoy and his girlfriend festively hire a prostitute for some **three-way high jinks**.*](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/relationships/my-wife-and-i-want-to-explore-our-options-in-the-bedroom/article1391620/) As ever, context (and spelling) is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was RyeBread's objection, not mine.  That said, I think a three-way jinx would require each to buy the other a coke.  And then to see who could open it the fastest.  That person would be declared the jinxer, and the others the jinxees.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not *jynges*? :) “a. mod.L. *jynx*, pl. *jynges*, = L. *iynx*, a. Gr. *ἴυγξ*, pl. *ἴυγγες* the wryneck, a bird made use of in witchcraft; hence, a charm, a spell.”

Comment: @tchrist: It was [one of your fellow countrymen](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152965/2637) who taught me about the wicked tooth[-rotting] fairy's plan to force us all to drink more Coke, in which context **jinx** is obviously a word associated with "the dark side". Of which I know little and believe less (I bet Darth Vader never even existed, and I certainly don't believe he was Luke's dad! :). Anyway, the point is I'm not responsible for *Yanx* using *Jinx*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For the record, lots of *other* massless particles *also* move at *c* (if I remember my relativity correctly, being massless actually **requires** that motion occur at *c*), light is just the most common/well-known of them. So it's not *everything* except light. It still does cover the overwhelming majority of things.

Comment: @KRyan: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massless_particle) *In particle physics, a massless particle is a particle whose invariant mass is zero. Currently, **the only known massless particles** are gauge bosons: the **photon** (carrier of electromagnetism) and the **gluon** (carrier of the strong force). However, gluons are never observed as free particles, since they are confined within **hadrons**.* And *hadrons* are either *baryons* (protons & neutrons), or *mesons* - which are too hard for me, but I don't think they zip around at lightspeed (certainly not for *long!* :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Huh. You are indeed correct, I didn't realize that photons were the only one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your bosons give me a hadron. ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen **[superluminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion)** and **subluminal**. Sometimes **sub-lightspeed**

Comment: I've definitely seen sub-lightspeed.

Comment: I would point out that the linked Wikipedia article, "Superluminal motion", concerns a phenomenon where something merely _appears_ to be moving faster than light despite not actually doing so. Nevertheless, physicists do use "superluminal" and "subluminal" to refer to true faster- and slower-than-light motion respectively, and most physicists would recognize these words as the closest equivalents to "supersonic" and "subsonic". (The phenomenon in the article probably shouldn't be called superluminal motion at all; it's just a misleading name we're stuck with due to tradition.)

Answer (score 4):

Particularly if you are referring to particles, you could use tachyonic for faster-than-light and bradyonic for slower-than-light.

Comment: Let's not leave this one out: [tardyonic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bradyon).

Comment: @Jim That sounds like you are late for music class . . .

Comment: *"bradyonic"* ..and that makes me think of the Brady Bunch.

Comment: @Jim: Presumably tardyonic refers to the speed of a TARDIS? ;-)

Comment: Speed has no meaning to a time lord.

Answer (score 1):

For speeds below the speed of light, you can consider the word **sublight** http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Sublight_engine

For speeds above the speed of light, you can consider **F.T.L.**, meaning faster-than-light.  [See here](http://www.gateworld.net/wiki/F.T.L.)

Comment: Are either of those used outside of science fiction?

Comment: @IQAndreas They are used colloquially among physicists.

Comment: any discussion of speeds equal to or greater than c is by definition science fiction.

Comment: @DougM There are plenty of ideas involving FTL event propagation which are more than science fiction even if not established fact either.  Tachyons, wormholes, and Alcubierre drive are all more than science fiction.  Even if none of them turn out to be true, or at least practical for communication/travel, they are still reasonable hypothesis to be considered given our current understanding.  The idea of FTL travel/communication is a useful one to have, even if it really is impossible.

Comment: @DougM *Equal to* or greater? The speed *c* appears quite frequently in works of science fact. :) Some things (e.g., light in vacuum) even go at that speed.

Comment: IQAndreas, I don't think that matters. They are still relevant to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Faster than light has to be Warp speed. Everything else is just normal, impulse power.

Comment: Notwithstanding the existence of some real-world *theoretical* analogues, warp speed is a fictional technology. Nor is "everything else" impulse power, unless you are generously inviting real technologies like solar sails under that umbrella. NASA Sunjammer, launching later this year!

Comment: This might be a reasonable answer on Science Fiction & Fantasy.SE: on ELU it is unhelpful.