# Is there an idiom that implies that you reach me when I was planning to reach you?

Tags: idiom-requests

I was planning to send an email to someone when actually this person reached me first!

I wanted to say "oh I was planning to reach you when you actually reach me first" Like in my native language we have a phrase we use. Is there anything like this in English literature or idiom?

Comment: Jinx or synchronicity? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152947/word-for-when-two-people-type-the-same-thing-at-the-same-time-in-chat

Comment: I am looking for an idiom, not a word! Only if this does not exist in the English language

Comment: The **idiom** is *jinx,* because the normal meaning is something that brings bad luck.